# Representation of $L^{\infty}(X)$ in $L^2(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f \in  L^{\infty}(X)$, $g \in  L^{2}(X)$, then $fg \in L^{2}(X)$. How can I prove that?

Then I can represent $L^{\infty}(X)$ in $\mathcal{B}(L^{2}(X)$ by the multiplication operator given by $f \to M_f$ where $M_f(g)=fg$. I want to prove that the commutant of 
$L^{\infty}(X)$ when regarded as a subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(L^{2}(X)$ is $L^{\infty}(X)$. Do I need to make any assumptions about the measure to hold these results?

Comment: $\|fg\|_{2}\le\|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{2}<\infty$.